# Find the limit of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}/e^n$ without using derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits

Try to use just basic operations with limits to find this one:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}{e^n}$$

I have some ideas. Is it possible that they are right?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}{e^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{((1+\frac{1}{n})^{n})^n}{e^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{n}}{e^n} = 1$$

Comment: Unfortunately $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\neq e$, so that substitution is incorrect. But it has the beginnings of a good idea.

Comment: But why e isn't $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, I just checked it again. I really need a hint then.

Comment: Go and check yourself for $n=1,2,\text{ or }3$. It is clearly not $\mathbf e$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Oh, so big numbers when $n$ is squared.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but when n is not squared it's ok. What is e if $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is not?

Comment: What is $(1+\frac12)^2$? What is $(1+\frac13)^3$? Is it the same number, to begin with? Is it $e$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin maybe Valery wants to say that $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$...

Comment: @IvanNeretin of course it's not. But we do limits, don't we? So when $n\to\infty$ why can't we say that it means e and simplify?

Comment: Because when you simplify like that, you lose something valuable. It is exactly the same as if you would "simplify" $1\over n$ to $0$ - after all, its limit is $0$, is it not? - in $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, and thus conclude that the said limit is 1, which (as you know) it is not.

Comment: @IvanNeretin thank you, I got what you meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let's see what is it, really.
$$\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}{e^n}=e^{n^2\log(1+{1\over n})-n}=e^{n^2\left({1\over n}-{1\over2n^2}+o(n^{-2})\right)-n}=e^{n-{1\over2}+o(1)-n}=e^{-{1\over2}+o(1)} \to {1\over\sqrt e}$$
Now let's think how can we make it simple.

Comment: It's awesome, but I do not understand everything that contains "o". Redirect me to wiki or something else if you can. Or even tell how to spell it to me google by myself. Thank you a lot.

Comment: That's the [big O/little o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).

Comment: definition of little-o notation I understood, really beautiful and useful idea. But how did you make transformations with it. The step when you canceled log out is unclear for me and for other calculus newbies. Another wiki link is really needed here.

Comment: I'm not really sure whether it is wholesome to read the entire course of calculus overnight, but anyway, I don't see how this could be done with simpler techniques. Well, this part makes use of the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions), especially the one for logarithm.

Comment: All day long I hear about Taylor series which ones forbidden for calculus on lessons till a moment. Looking forward to understanding them. Thanks a lot, Ivan, for all your help.

Answer (score 4):

Since
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}&=&n^2
\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=n^2\left[\frac1n-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{3n^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right]\\
&=&n-\frac12+\frac{1}{3n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),
\end{eqnarray}
we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}}{e^n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left[-\frac12+\frac{1}{3n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right]=e^{-\frac12}.
$$